# Perl script to change the file name

Tags: perl

i have a file called tc1.log, in that file a line started with

```
SVSEED set randomly from command line: -729040569
```

Now i want a perl script to read the number (`-729040569`) and same time it has to append to my log file likewise `[tc1_-729040569.log]`. How to do this by using perl script.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Have you looked at `rename`?

Comment: No i haven't tried it. i'm trying, No i haven't looked at rename

Comment: So what are you asking us? Do you expect us to just write the whole script for you?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with the `makefile` tag?

Comment: if i get complete with the the perl script. i i will write a loop in makefile to execut the target in makefile. That means i will call this perl script in the makefile.

Comment: grep 'svseed' tc_1/tc1.log | awk '{print $7}' i want this command to use in perl script. how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $filename = 'tc1.log';
open (FILE, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my $new_name = $filename;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ m/SVSEED set randomly from command line: (\S+)/) {
     my $seed = $1;
     $new_name =~ s/.log/${seed}.log/;
     last;
  }
}
close FILE;
rename $filename, $new_name if $filename ne $new_name;
```

Comment: now i changed the log file name to ncverilog.log its printing like ncver110973737 like this i want like this ncverilog_110973737

Comment: Please use lexical filehandles in example code. Best to not teach beginners outdated practices.

Comment: @abhishek: If you study and understand the code, I think it will become obvious which line you need to change. We're not here to do all of your thinking for you.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it